# How to use numpad as mouse pointer (moving and clicks)?

Tags: 16.04, accessibility, remapping

I want to use the keypad to move the mouse to all directions and right and left click. How can I do this?

Comment: What flavor are you using? Can you add more information and context so someone may be able to provide you the correct answer?

Comment: @Zzzach... I think now it is clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to *Universal Access*>*Pointing and clicking*>*Mouse keys: Control the pointerwith keypad* and swicth to **ON**.
[image]

Then your numpad will work as follows:

- **1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9**: move the mouse pointer up,down,left,right and diagonals
- **5**: left click
- **0**: click and hold. it will release when clicking 5
- **-**: turns 5 to right-click
- *: turns 5 back to left-click
- **Enter**: still being enter
- **+** and **,**: Double click
- **.** and **/** : I still dont know